# Reference a component's nested variable from a service, or vice versa

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs, angular6

In `Angular 6`, I'd like to access a component's nested (local, inside a function) variable from my service.

**myComponent.ts**

```
myFunction() {
   var componentArray = [];
}
```

**myService.ts**

```
myServiceFunction() {
   if (errorExists) {
      componentArray.push("error exists!"); //how can I do this?
   }
}
```

Is this possible? I'm able to reference global properties or functions of other components, but what about accessing local variables within those functions?

Comment: BTW, I realize there is a lot wrong with this question fundamentally. I'm just having a yuge brain fart today...

Comment: you can't.you shouldn't access component variables from service you should do other way.access service from component

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha, thanks - I thought this may be the case. Say the scenario was reversed and I wanted to access a service's nested variable from my component - is this possible?

Comment: no still not possible.local variables are not accessible from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subscriber pattern to communicate between the service and the component.

The service would expose an observable that emits the error message when it happens, and the component would subscribe to receive those messages.

You have to decide if this should be a Subject, BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject. Depending upon your needs, but here I'll just use a Subject.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private _errors: Subject<string> = new Subject();

    public getErrors(): Observable<string> { 
       return this._errors.asObservable();
    }

    public someFunction() {
       if(errorExists) {
          this._errors.next("error exists");
       }
    }
}
```

The component would then listen for these errors, and add them to the array.

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implement OnDestroy, OnInit {
   private componentArray = [];

   private readonly _destroyed$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

   public constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

   public ngOnDestroy() {
      this._destroyed$.next();
      this._destroyed$.complete();
   }

   public ngOnInit() {
       const functionArray = [];

       this.myService.getErrors().pipe(
           takeUntil(this._destroyed$)
       ).subscribe(error => {
           this.componentArray.push(error);
           functionArray.push(error);
       });
   }
}
```

How you use the value after it's been added to the array is up to you. If you modify a component property that is used in the template, then you'll need to mark the view as dirty to notify Angular that change detection is needed.

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef